# load php/mysql data to amcharts using dataloader

Tags: php, mysql, json, amcharts

I am new to AmCharts and having trouble to display the simple graph that I needed. I have used codes from the AmCharts live editor. This is the PHP file (getGred.php)

```
   $query = "SELECT gred, COUNT( gred ) AS bilangan FROM borg_peribadi GROUP BY gred";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
//echo $query;
//echo "<br>";
$rows = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
     $rows[] = array(
    "gred" => $data[ 'gred' ],
    "bilangan" => $data[ 'bilangan' ]
  );
  }

  echo json_encode( $rows );
```

And this is what I got from AmCharts tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laporan eOrientasi</title>
        <meta name="description" content="chart created using amCharts live editor" />

        <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
        <script src="../amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- amCharts plugins -->
        <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js type="text/javascript""></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css">
        <script src="../amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
                {
                    "type": "serial",
                    "dataLoader": {
                        "url": "getGred.php",
                        "format": "json"
                    },
                    "categoryField": "gred",
                    "angle": 30,
                    "depth3D": 30,
                    "startDuration": 1,
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "gridPosition": "start"
                    },
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "chartScrollbar": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "trendLines": [],
                    "graphs": [
                        {
                            "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                            "fillAlphas": 1,
                            "id": "AmGraph-1",
                            "title": "bil. pegawai",
                            "type": "column",
                            "valueField": "bilangan"
                        }
                    ],
                    "guides": [],
                    "valueAxes": [
                        {
                            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                            "title": "Bilangan"
                        }
                    ],
                    "allLabels": [],
                    "balloon": {},
                    "legend": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "useGraphSettings": true
                    },
                    "titles": [
                        {
                            "id": "Title-1",
                            "size": 15,
                            "text": "BIL PEGAWAI MELAPOR DIRI MENGIKUT GRED"
                        }
                    ],
                //  "dataProvider":  AmCharts.loadJSON('laporan/getGred.php')

                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is not the graph is not showing, only displays below:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8f1x.png)

Hope to get some pointers on any of errors or mistakes. Thank you.

edit: i've added the output from getGred.php

> [{"gred":"29","bilangan":"1"},{"gred":"41","bilangan":"5"},{"gred":"44","bilangan":"6"}]

Comment: What is the data that dataLoader receives from your php script? You can use the postProcess option to console.log what data you get: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32440230/775103. Also, you dataloader script path looks different than the other amcharts paths. Coincidence?

Comment: This is the data:  [{"gred":"29","bilangan":"1"},{"gred":"41","bilangan":"5"},{"gred":"44","bilangan":"6"}] . i've corrected the path but it still does not work

Comment: Have you tried to remove quotes from the bilangan values?

Comment: tried that $rows = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
  $rows[] = array(
    "gred" => $data[ 'gred' ],
    "bilangan" => (int)$data['bilangan']
  );
  }
   which displays:  [{"gred":"29","bilangan":1},{"gred":"41","bilangan":5},{"gred":"44","bilangan":6}]    . still the same

Comment: Any errors in your JS console? Not sure why nothing is displaying. This codepen works fine: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e8f14854a8f49049e30fd0bb99046046?editors=0010. (not using dataLoader unfortunately)

Comment: sorry, there is one, i've missed it out. Error - dataloader.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dataLoader' of undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ dataloader.min.js:1
outputGred.php:17 GET https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js%20type= 404 ()

Comment: Looks like you didn't include the export plugin properly. Make sure the quotes are correct.